# Flexbox keep child widths static with set number per row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to create a group of buttons that need to be centered and in even groups (this example 3 per row). However, my options seem to be either group them but allow width growth by adding to the child:

```
flex: 0 0 20%
```

or keep them static width and allow the flex-wrap to change their position based on screen size. 
Is there a way to allow both? I.e. for large screen sizes, have 2 groups of 3 buttons and allow appropriate wrapping for smaller screens, but always keep the static widths?

```css
    .parent {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .child{
      text-decoration: none !important;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 160px;
      height: 140px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
      border-radius: 30px;
      border: 1px solid #003595;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a class="child" href="blah">
      <i class="fa fa-broadcast-tower fa-5x"></i>
      <span>Button 1</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
      <i class="fa fa-chart-line fa-5x"></i>
      <span>Button 2</span>  
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
      <i class="fa fa-address-card fa-5x"></i>
      <span>Button 3</span>
  </a>                    
  <a class="child" href="blah">
      <i class="fa fa-clipboard-list fa-5x"></i>
      <span>Button 4</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
      <i class="fa fa-signal fa-5x"></i>
      <span>Button 5</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
      <i class="fa fa-signal fa-5x"></i>
      <span>Button 6</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ms1t8xry/) to show/play with the resizing.

Comment: They look great and exactly as you described so where is the problem?

Comment: I am a bit confused with what you are asking, if you set width to fixed value and flex wrap to wrap, then it will already wrap when needed by itself. What is the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: @Tarek.hms They either don't remain in groups of 3 (look at the fiddle, it will show 5 on one row and 1 on the next) or dont remain static widths if I use flexflow.

Comment: @Huangism They don't have a preset grouping of 3. See fiddle.

Comment: @JWiley what do you mean by grouping? as in you want 3 per row at max?

Comment: @JWiley, ok i got it now

Comment: @Huangism yep! Exactly that.

Comment: @JWiley then just add a child with width 100% after each 3 or put 3 items in one flex container

Comment: ...or you'd have to calculate the margins you need and use `justify-content:space between`

Comment: Yea or calculate margins, I see a lot of people using flex with tons of child under one parent and unable to achieve a specific layout but it is much easier to put them into different flex containers

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I didn't think to split the container into multiples, great idea. @Paulie_D could you provide an example with the margins and justify-content?

Comment: I'd have to work out the calculation but CSS-Grid offers a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you need your buttons to be centered, so how about adding a `max-width` to the parent, and then center everything with `margin: auto` and `justify-content: center`? That way it will also wrap correctly on smaller screens:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    max-width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ms1t8xry/9/

Answer (score 0):

**CSS-Grid** can do that

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bjXaNb)

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.child {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  width: 160px;
  height: 140px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #003595;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="parent">
  <a class="child" href="blah">
    <i class="fa fa-broadcast-tower fa-5x"></i>
    <span>Button 1</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
    <i class="fa fa-chart-line fa-5x"></i>
    <span>Button 2</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
    <i class="fa fa-address-card fa-5x"></i>
    <span>Button 3</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
    <i class="fa fa-clipboard-list fa-5x"></i>
    <span>Button 4</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
    <i class="fa fa-signal fa-5x"></i>
    <span>Button 5</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
    <i class="fa fa-signal fa-5x"></i>
    <span>Button 6</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

**Flexbox** requires us to calculate the margins

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  flex: 0 0 160px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 1em calc((100% - (160px *3)) / 7); /* I think it's 7 */
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #003595;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="parent">
  <a class="child" href="blah">
    <i class="fa fa-broadcast-tower fa-5x"></i>
    <span>Button 1</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
    <i class="fa fa-chart-line fa-5x"></i>
    <span>Button 2</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
    <i class="fa fa-address-card fa-5x"></i>
    <span>Button 3</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
    <i class="fa fa-clipboard-list fa-5x"></i>
    <span>Button 4</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
    <i class="fa fa-signal fa-5x"></i>
    <span>Button 5</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
    <i class="fa fa-signal fa-5x"></i>
    <span>Button 6</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks- this is a great solution, but I'm interested in how you would do this using flexbox. This also would enable scrolling for smaller screens instead of wrapping the items.

Answer (score 0):

For flex solution, you can just use a divider flex child to separate the rows and set its width to 100%. I also added `justify-content: space-between` for the container. There is no need for margin calculation since you have a divider

```css
.parent {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .child{
      text-decoration: none !important;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 160px;
      height: 140px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
      border-radius: 30px;
      border: 1px solid #003595;
    }
    .divider {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a class="child" href="blah">
      <i class="fa fa-broadcast-tower fa-5x"></i>
      <span>Button 1</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
      <i class="fa fa-chart-line fa-5x"></i>
      <span>Button 2</span>  
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
      <i class="fa fa-address-card fa-5x"></i>
      <span>Button 3</span>
  </a>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
      <i class="fa fa-clipboard-list fa-5x"></i>
      <span>Button 4</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
      <i class="fa fa-signal fa-5x"></i>
      <span>Button 5</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="blah">
      <i class="fa fa-signal fa-5x"></i>
      <span>Button 6</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Or As I mentioned before you could just put them into 2 different flex containers. They all work, you can pick whichever solution suits you the best